# swa start - cant find dotnet

Tags: .net, command-line-interface

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
swa start http://localhost:5000 --run "dotnet run --project Client/Admin.Portal.Client.csproj"             --api-location Admin.Portal.Api
[run] The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
[run]   * You intended to execute a .NET application:
[run]       The application 'run' does not exist.
[run]   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
[run]       No .NET SDKs were found.
[run] 
[run] Download a .NET SDK:
[run] https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
[run] 
[run] Learn about SDK resolution:
[run] https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

This is working:

```
❯ dotnet --list-sdks
2.2.402 [/home/dan/.dotnet/sdk]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
3.1.426 [/home/xxx/.dotnet/sdk]
6.0.416 [/home/xxx/.dotnet/sdk]
7.0.400 [/home/xxx/.dotnet/sdk]
7.0.403 [/home/xxx/.dotnet/sdk]
8.0.100 [/home/xxx/.dotnet/sdk]
8.0.101 [/home/xxx/.dotnet/sdk]
```

Comment: swa found other dotnet executeable remove that and now it works